# Android cannot change button text

Tags: android, button, crash

I know this is the stupid question but i don't know why it happen.
Here my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setText("Blabla");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aiueo);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

Fragment XML:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="next" />
```

I just want to change the text when start activity but it crash my app.

Logcat

```
06-23 15:42:05.396: E/AndroidRuntime(13039): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 15:42:05.396: E/AndroidRuntime(13039): Process: com.shinway.hiragana, PID: 13039
06-23 15:42:05.396: E/AndroidRuntime(13039): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shinway.hiragana/com.shinway.hiragana.table.Aiueo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-23 15:42:05.396: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
06-23 15:42:05.396: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
06-23 15:42:05.396: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
06-23 15:42:05.396: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
06-23 15:42:05.396: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-23 15:42:05.396: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-23 15:42:05.396: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5144)
06-23 15:42:05.396: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 15:42:05.396: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-23 15:42:05.396: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
06-23 15:42:05.396: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
06-23 15:42:05.396: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-23 15:42:05.396: E/AndroidRuntime(13039): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-23 15:42:05.396: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at com.shinway.hiragana.table.Aiueo.onCreate(Aiueo.java:37)
06-23 15:42:05.396: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-23 15:42:05.396: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at  android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-23 15:42:05.396: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
06-23 15:42:05.396: E/AndroidRuntime(13039):    ... 11 more
```

Without the settext code. Everything else run fine. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the order like

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_aiueo);

 Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
 button.setText("Blabla");
```

You should first `setContentView(R.layout.activity_aiueo);` and then reference `Button` View
and make sure you've button with **Id** `button2` in your `activity_aiueo` layout.

Comment: I think OP need move code to fragment class too, because this layout is not `activity_aiueo` ( I think )

Comment: Move that code under setContentView not work too !
I think @shayanpourvatan right, it's about something in fragment layout

Comment: @JeremyPham if you've button2 in your Fragment layout then move your button click code in Fragment

Comment: @JeremyPham `Simple plan` answer is correct, but you post xml layout as Fragment name, I guess that you have a fragment class so you need paste your code in onCreateView(), be ware that you need inflate your view and use `view.findViewById()`.

Comment: Thank you. I change my XML to Activity not Fragment anymore and it's work. Thank :D

Answer (score 0):

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_aiueo);
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
button.setText("Blabla");
```

Declare button and use it to set text after setcontentView() will solve your crash issue

Comment: ... which is the very same answer that `Simple Plan` gave before you.

Comment: actually we posted at same time. when i saw this question no answers was available.

Answer (score 0):

If you designed more then one layout file for different screen size must named same id. if the id mismatches this will happen.

for example

```
    public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
        t.setText("Secoknd text to display!"); 
        }   
    }
```

Layout/main.xml

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="38dp"
     android:editable="true"
     android:text="TextView" />
```

Layout-large-hdpi/main.xml

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView2"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="38dp"
     android:editable="true"
     android:text="TextView" />
```

If you run on an ldpi mobile it works. but if you run on an hdpi mobile it cant find id textView1. So you application stops its working.